# Encrypt then decrypt an SWF file with PHP and Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, encryption, mcrypt

would someone kindly provide me with the simplest forms of encrypting a file with PHP using mcrypt "say .swf" and then decrypting it in my flex application?

thank you in advance.

ps: the file will be served to the Flex application through read_file($file); function.

Rami

Comment: So you wish to encrypt the binary data of the SWF? or an mcrypt functionality within AS3?

Comment: I wish to encrypt the binary data of the swf example encrypt($file,$key); then decrypt it in the flex app, i don't mind using crypto and mcrypt but i would like to have a starting point .. thanks for the reply

Comment: Your subject is a bit misleading; since you don't want to encrypt a SWF, you want to encrypt data.  Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/ or http://ascrypt3.riaforge.org/index.cfm for encryption / decryption on the client. I don't know PHP libraries enough to make a recommendation there though.